# AD user is not allowed to connect to Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I have a user Domain\Test with which I am able to connect my custom java client application to database on the on-premise SQL server. But when I installed the application.exe on Azure Virtual machine and after I migrated my on-premise SQL server to Azure SQL server then I am unable to connect to the Azure database anymore.

It throws an error saying "The user Domain\Test is not allowed to connect". The user is an Active directory user.

What can be the cause? Do I need to register my application and user credentials on Azure portal? Please provide your thoughts.

Kind regards,

Sam

Comment: Azure SQL runs on an Azure domain. You need an Azure AD account to connect to the database, unless federation between the Azure AD and local AD domains is configured. Did you try to connect with an Azure AD user or a local AD user? Have you added any users to the Azure SQL database? Have you tried connecting from SSMS or Azure Data Studio?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am able to connect to Azure SQL Database using SSMS , but I have  a custom Java application which is also installed on Azure Virtual machine[IAAS] .I am unable to establish a connect from this custom client application to Azure SQL  database while it works very well when I try to connect to the on Premises SQL server.Could  you please suggest if i need to register the user in Azure AD or any other place ?

Comment: @sameer if you want to access Azure SQL database with AD user, it must be registered to the Azure domain. Or add the AD user to Azure AD user group.

Comment: @sameer have you added the Azure Virtual machine's IP to the Azure SQL Server's firewall rule?